# SQL Query If Condition for specific text within two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a query, but I'm not exactly sure how to write it. I need to grab all the EmployeeIds based off the status. If it is completed and pending, completed takes precedence. However, if there is only pending and not completed I'll take pending, else don't take any of the rows for that employee. I just need one item per EmployeeId.  Technically I would also need to grab the earliest date but I think I would know how to write that part.

```
RowNumber  Status    EmployeeId   Produce       Date
-------------------------------------------------------
1          New          1            Apples     1/1/18
2          Pending      1           BlueBerry   1/2/18
3          New          1           Oranges     1/3/18
4          Pending      2            Bananas    1/1/18
5          New          2            Grapes     1/2/18
6          Complete     2            Limes      1/3/18
```

So in this example I need the following below

```
RowNumber  Status    EmployeeId    Produce       Date
--------------------------------------------------------
2          Pending      1           BlueBerry   1/2/18
6          Complete     2            Limes      1/3/18
```

The hardest part for me is trying to figure out how to compare strings.  Basically (semi pseudo-code)

```
Select top 1 
    t.EmployeeId, t.Produce, t.Date, stat.Status
    (Case
        If t.Status = 'Complete'
           Select 'Complete'
        If t.Status = 'Pending'
           Select 'Pending'
        Else
           Dont Add this row ) stat
From 
    Table t 
Where 
    t.Status = 'Complete' or t.Status = 'Pending'
Order by 
    t.Date
```

Answer (score 2):

There's at least two different approaches coming to my mind :

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeId
           FROM Table
          WHERE Status = "Complete"

          UNION

SELECT DISTINCT t1.EmployeeId
           FROM Table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table t2
             ON t2.EmployeeId = t1.EmployeeId
            AND t2.Status = "Complete"
          WHERE t1.Status = "Pending"
            AND t2.Status IS NULL
```

… or using `coalesce()` if your database engine supports it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pend.EmployeeId,
                coalesce(comp.Status,pend.Status),
                coalesce(comp.RowNumber,pend.RowNumber)
           FROM MyTable pend
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable comp
             ON comp.EmployeeId = pend.EmployeeId
            AND comp.Status = 'Complete'
          WHERE pend.Status IN ('Complete','Pending');
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want using `row_number()` :

```
select top (1) with ties *
from table t
where Status in ('Completed', 'Pending')
order by row_number() over (partition by EmployeeId 
                                 order by (case Status when 'Completed' 
                                                       then 0 
                                                       when 'Pending' 
                                                       then 1  
                                           end)
                           );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a UNION ALL coupled with a WHERE NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM [Table] t1
WHERE [Status] = 'Completed'
UNION ALL   
SELECT t2.*
FROM [Table] t2
WHERE [Status] = 'Pending'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM [Table] 
        WHERE EmployeeId = t2.EmployeeId 
            AND [Status] = [Completed]
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate a ROW_NUMBER that uses a CASE WHEN.

And then filter on that.

**For example:**

```
SELECT RowNumber, [Status], EmployeeId, Produce, [Date]
FROM
(
  SELECT  
   RowNumber, [Status], EmployeeId, Produce, [Date],
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY EmployeeId 
      ORDER BY [Date] DESC, 
                CASE [Status] WHEN 'Complete' THEN 1 WHEN 'Pending' THEN 2 ELSE 9 END
      ) AS RN
   FROM [YourTable] t 
   WHERE [Status] IN ('Complete','Pending')
) q
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY EmployeeId
```